# macOS won't use the right PHP version

Tags: macos, bash, php, homebrew, macos-mojave

I just updated *macOS* to Mojave, updated `brew` and reinstalled `php` (version 7.3, still via brew).

If I run `php` I get

```
-bash: /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php: No such file or directory
```

But if I do `which php` I get

```
/usr/bin/php
```

(that `php -v` reports as 7.1.23)

Makes no sense.
**Why does `php` calls a path different reported by `which`?**
And how can I make the system use the last version rather than those wrong ones?

I tried to `brew unlink php && brew link php` but when I run `php` it still calls the version 7.2 instead of the 7.3 that I just installed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was with the `/usr/local/bin` appearing in PATH environment variable **after** `/usr/bin` (reported by `brew doctor`).

I fixed easily adding

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

to `.bash_profile` (or `.bashrc`) in the user home directory.

Don't really like the solution since I'd like to know why `/usr/bin` comes **before** `/usr/local/bin` (that, in *macOS*, is supposed provide the chance to override the paths) in the first place.